# Where to verify or change config of urg_node?

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node, urg-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When reviewing the URGConfig.dox and comparing to the HokuyoConfig.dox there are several differences and I would like to test the urg_node with the values the same as with the hokuyo_node. If I edit the URGConfig.dox will this affect changes to the urg_node or do I need to access a different file to make these changes?

Example:

```
\b "~angle_min" : \b [double] Controls the angle of the first range measurement in radians. min: -3.14159265359, default: -3.14159265359, max: 3.14159265359
```

In the HokuyoConfig.dox for the same "~angle_min" it has the default at
-1.57079632679; so again, what file do I change in the urg_node to get the settings the same as for the hokuyo_node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64733/where-to-verify-or-change-config-of-urg_node?/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2013-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Configuration in ROS is not done with one config file per node.  You use what's called the parameter server:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/Parameter%20Server

The files you are finding (cfgs) are for a very convenient way to change parameters without restarting the node: dynamic reconfigure.

http://ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node/Tutorials/UsingReconfigureGUIToChangeHokuyoLaserParameters

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't need to edit the cfg files.

Instead, you can set the parameters in your launch file, and they will be read in when the program starts.

```
<node name="urg_node" pkg="urg_node" type="urg_node" output="screen">
  <param name="angle_min" value="-1.5707963"/>
</node>
```

As much as possible, you shouldn't have to modify the original package for things like setting parameters.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2013-06-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2